# OLAP cube connection displayed in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ssas, olap

I am creating a pivot table in Excel 2010 using a connection to an OLAP cube.

I am trying to figure out how to have the path and file name of the cube and the last refreshed date/time to be displayed and printed into the Excel sheet.

Basically, the same information that is displayed in the Workbook Connections (under the data tab) to be printed within the sheet where the pivot table is located.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This will print all of the connection names to the debug window.

```
Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
   Debug.Print conn.Name
Next conn
```

Similarly, you can display information on the sheet.